# I want to show a column with some special charcter in SQL

Tags: sql, hive, special-characters, alias

I need to extract a column[Employee] in DB as "Employee(Emp)" in Hive.
Is that possible we can handle in hive.

```
Select Employee as Employee(Emp) from Emp_Table
```

But it seems doesnt work as expected

Comment: Select Employee as "Employee(Emp)" from Emp_Table  Hope, this works

Comment: @Sergey..It was throwing an error.missing EOF llike that.I am using Hive for my execution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use backtick (``` `` ```) to enclose the alias.

```
Select 'aa' as `Employee(Emp)`
```

[image]